# Django: Implementing a dependent dropdown list in a form

Tags: javascript, python, django

Hello StackOverflow community!

I am new to programming and am currently working on a Django-based website for ITSM ticket management. My site has two main components:

```
A ticket manager that displays created tickets, their status, address, assigned technician, problem description, etc.
An administrative part in Django, which only certain users have access to.
```

I am having trouble implementing a ticket creation or update form. I am trying to implement a dependent dropdown list functionality: when a district is selected in the ticket creation form, only a list of technicians associated with that district should be displayed in the "Technician" field.

I am unsure of how to correctly implement this functionality. Maybe I should use JavaScript or AJAX, or is there a way to do this directly in Django? Your guidance or pointers would be highly valuable.

Thank you for your assistance!

```
**models.py**
`from django.db import models

from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils.formats import date_format
from django import forms

class Ticket(models.Model):
STATUSES = (
('new', 'Новый'),
('in_progress', 'В работе'),
('overdue', 'Просрочен'),
('deferred', 'Отложенный')
)

DEVICE_CHOICES = [
    ('Выберите тип прибора', 'Выберите тип прибора'),
    ('Stemax', 'Stemax'),
    ('Приток', 'Приток'),
    ('Болид', 'Болид'),
    ('Альтоника', 'Альтоника'),
]

title = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='Default Title')  # Добавлено новое поле
status = models.CharField('Статус', max_length=20, choices=STATUSES, default='new')
date_created = models.DateTimeField('Дата создания', auto_now_add=True)
date_completed = models.DateTimeField('Дата завершения', null=True, blank=True)
control_number = models.AutoField('Номер заявки', primary_key=True)
manual_control_number = models.PositiveIntegerField('Пультовой номер', null=True, blank=True)
device_type = models.CharField('Тип прибора', max_length=50, choices=DEVICE_CHOICES,     default='Выберите тип прибора', blank=False)
owner = models.CharField('Заказчик', max_length=200, null=True)
district = models.CharField('Район', max_length=100)
address = models.TextField('Адрес', max_length=200)
technician = models.CharField('Техник', max_length=200, blank=True)
description = models.TextField('Описание')
comment = models.TextField('Комментарий', blank=True)

@property
def is_overdue(self):
    return self.date_completed < timezone.now()

def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.get_status_display()} - {self.manual_control_number}"

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Заявку'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Заявки'

class Act(models.Model):
ticket = models.ForeignKey(Ticket, related_name='acts', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
act_file = models.FileField(upload_to='acts/')

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Акт'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Акты'`

**forms.py**

from django import forms
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from .models import Ticket, Act

class TicketForm(forms.ModelForm):
date_completed = forms.DateTimeField(
    label='Дата завершения',
    widget=forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={'type': 'datetime-local'}),
    required=False,
)

DEVICE_CHOICES = [
    ('', 'Выберите тип прибора'),
    ('Stemax', 'Stemax'),
    ('Приток', 'Приток'),
    ('Болид', 'Болид'),
    ('Альтоника', 'Альтоника'),
]
device_type = forms.ChoiceField(
    label='Тип прибора',
    choices=DEVICE_CHOICES,
    initial='Выберите тип прибора',
)

class Meta:
    model = Ticket
    fields = ['date_completed', 'manual_control_number', 'device_type', 'owner', 'district',    'address', 'technician', 'description', 'comment']

    labels = {
        'status': 'Статус',
        'date_completed': 'Дата завершения',
        'manual_control_number': 'Пультавой номер',
        'device_type': 'Тип прибора',
        'owner': 'Заказчик',
        'district': 'Район',
        'address': 'Адрес',
        'technician': 'Техник',
        'description': 'Описание',
        'comment': 'Комментарий',
    }


class StartWorkForm(forms.Form):
technician = forms.CharField(required=False)
date_completed = forms.DateTimeField(required=False, widget=forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={'type':   'datetime-local'}))


class LoginForm(forms.Form):
username = forms.CharField()
password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)


class ActForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Act
    fields = ['act_file']  # Поле file не существует в модели Act, исправлено на act_file


def add_act(request, ticket_id):
ticket = get_object_or_404(Ticket, id=ticket_id)

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ActForm(request.POST, request.FILES)  # Не передаем существующий акт в форму
    if form.is_valid():
        act = form.save(commit=False)
        act.ticket = ticket
        act.save()
        return redirect('ticket_detail', ticket_id=ticket_id)
else:
    form = ActForm()  # Не передаем существующий акт в форму

return render(request, 'ticket_manager/add_act.html', {'form': form})

**views.py**
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required, user_passes_test
from django.contrib import messages
from .models import Ticket
from .forms import TicketForm
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .forms import LoginForm
from django.contrib.auth import logout
from datetime import datetime
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from django.contrib.auth.views import logout_then_login
from .forms import ActForm


class DashboardView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
template_name = 'ticket_list.html'


def logout_view(request):
return logout_then_login(request, login_url='login/')


def login_view(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = LoginForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = authenticate(request, username=form.cleaned_data['username'],     password=form.cleaned_data['password'])
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
else:
    form = LoginForm()
return render(request, 'registration/login.html', {'form': form})


@login_required
@user_passes_test(lambda u: Group.objects.get(name='Dispatcher') in u.groups.all() or                                       u.is_superuser)
 def ticket_update(request, ticket_id):
ticket = get_object_or_404(Ticket, control_number=ticket_id)
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = TicketForm(request.POST, instance=ticket)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Ticket successfully updated.')
        return redirect('ticket_manager:ticket_list')
else:
    form = TicketForm(instance=ticket)
return render(request, 'ticket_manager/ticket_form.html', {'form': form, 'ticket': ticket})


@login_required
def ticket_list(request):
status = request.GET.get('status')
date_created = request.GET.get('date_created')
technician = request.GET.get('technician')
sort_type = request.GET.get('sort_type')

tickets = Ticket.objects.all()

if status:
    tickets = tickets.filter(status=status)
if date_created:
    tickets = tickets.filter(date_created=date_created)
if technician:
    tickets = tickets.filter(technician=technician)

if sort_type == 'asc':
    tickets = tickets.order_by('date_created')
else:
    tickets = tickets.order_by('-date_created')

is_dispatcher = Group.objects.get(name='Dispatcher') in request.user.groups.all() or   request.user.is_superuser

# Количество элементов на странице
items_per_page = 10

paginator = Paginator(tickets, items_per_page)
page_number = request.GET.get('page')

try:
    page_obj = paginator.page(page_number)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    page_obj = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    page_obj = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

return render(request, 'ticket_manager/ticket_list.html', {'page_obj': page_obj,    'is_dispatcher': is_dispatcher})


@login_required
def ticket_detail(request, ticket_id):
ticket = get_object_or_404(Ticket, pk=ticket_id)
return render(request, 'ticket_detail.html', {'ticket': ticket})


@login_required
@user_passes_test(lambda u: Group.objects.get(name='Dispatcher') in u.groups.all() or     u.is_superuser)
def ticket_create(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = TicketForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        ticket = form.save(commit=False)
        ticket.device_type = form.cleaned_data['device_type']
        ticket.save()
        return redirect('/ticket_list')
else:
    form = TicketForm()
return render(request, 'ticket_manager/ticket_form.html', {'form': form})


def add_act(request, ticket_id):
ticket = get_object_or_404(Ticket, id=ticket_id)
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ActForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        act = form.save(commit=False)
        act.ticket = ticket
        act.save()
        return redirect('ticket_detail', ticket_id=ticket_id)
else:
    form = ActForm()
return render(request, 'ticket_manager/add_act.html', {'form': form})

def cancel_ticket(request, pk):
ticket = get_object_or_404(Ticket, pk=pk)
if ticket.status != 'deferred':
ticket.status = 'deferred'
ticket.save()
return redirect('ticket_manager:ticket_list')

def confirm_cancel(request, ticket_id):
ticket = get_object_or_404(Ticket, pk=ticket_id)
return render(request, 'ticket_manager/confirm_cancel.html', {'ticket_id': ticket_id})

**\<!-- ticket_form.html --\>**
{% extends 'ticket_manager/base.html' %}

{% load static %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}

{% block extrahead %}
\<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'ticket_manager/styles.css' %}"\>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}




  {% if ticket.control_number %}
   <h2>Обновление заявки</h2>
  {% else %}
  <h2>Новая заявка</h2>
  {% endif %}
  
    {% csrf_token %}
    
      {% for field in form %}
        
          {{ field.label }}
          {{ field|add_class:"form-control" }}
          {% if field.help_text %}
            {{ field.help_text }}
          {% endif %}
          {% for error in field.errors %}
            
              {{ error }}
            
          {% endfor %}
        
      {% endfor %}
    
    Сохранить
  




  // Получаем элемент формы по id
  const form = document.getElementById("ticket-form");
  // Добавляем обработчик события submit
  form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
 // Предотвращаем стандартное поведение формы
 event.preventDefault();
// Получаем все поля формы
const fields = form.elements;
// Создаем переменную для хранения результата валидации
let isValid = true;
// Перебираем все поля формы
for (let i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
  // Получаем текущее поле
  const field = fields[i];
  // Проверяем, является ли поле обязательным
  if (field.required) {
    // Проверяем, заполнено ли поле
    if (!field.value) {
      // Если нет, выводим сообщение об ошибке и меняем значение isValid на false
      alert(`Пожалуйста, заполните поле ${field.name}`);
      isValid = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  // Если поле - это device_type
  if (field.name === 'device_type') {
    // Проверяем, является ли выбранное значение "Выберите тип прибора"
    if (field.value === 'Выберите тип прибора') {
      // Если да, выводим сообщение об ошибке и предотвращаем отправку формы
      alert('Пожалуйста, выберите тип прибора');
      isValid = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  // Проверяем, есть ли у поля атрибут pattern
  if (field.pattern) {
    // Создаем регулярное выражение из атрибута pattern
    const regex = new RegExp(field.pattern);
    // Проверяем, соответствует ли значение поля регулярному выражению
    if (!regex.test(field.value)) {
      // Если нет, выводим сообщение об ошибке и меняем значение isValid на false
      alert(`Пожалуйста, введите данные в правильном формате для поля ${field.name}`);
      isValid = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  // Проверяем, есть ли у поля атрибут minlength
  if (field.minlength) {
    // Проверяем, не меньше ли длина значения поля минимальной длины
    if (field.value.length < field.minlength) {
      // Если да, выводим сообщение об ошибке и меняем значение isValid на false
      alert(`Пожалуйста, введите не менее ${field.minlength} символов для поля ${field.name}`);
      isValid = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  // Проверяем, есть ли у поля атрибут maxlength
  if (field.maxlength) {
    // Проверяем, не больше ли длина значения поля максимальной длины
    if (field.value.length > field.maxlength) {
      // Если да, выводим сообщение об ошибке и меняем значение isValid на false
      alert(`Пожалуйста, введите не более ${field.maxlength} символов для поля ${field.name}`);
      isValid = false;
      break;
    }
  }
}
// Проверяем, является ли результат валидации истинным
if (isValid) {
  // Если да, отправляем форму на сервер
  form.submit();
}
```

});

```
{% endblock %}
```

I am unsure of how to correctly implement this functionality. Maybe there's a more effective way    to use JavaScript, AJAX, or a built-in Django method that I haven't tried? Your guidance or pointers   would be highly valuable.